# Getting error from fdf_get_value()

Tags: php, fdf

I was trying to get field value from fdf file. I have used following code, but getting error.

```
<?php
$fdf = fdf_open("test1.fdf");
echo "Name: ",fdf_get_value($fdf,"first_name");
fdf_close($fdf);
?>
```

Error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function fdf_get_value() in C:\LocalServer\htdocs\pdf\test.php on line 3

Do I have to install any library function? I do not know what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have the library installed - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/fdf.requirements.php

Comment: Thanks for help. I was trying to install but cannot understand which files and where it should be installed. I have downloaded FdF toolkit and the library function is available for C, Perl, FDFAcX. I am using xampp. Would you tell me which files and where it should be installed?

Comment: It's all there - http://www.php.net/manual/en/fdf.installation.php - see win32 note